# Ways to prevent heavy computation on every render in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app made with React. I have an array of games, which I need to display in certain way. The way I'm processing those games in my view is rather heavy, so I decided to prevent calculating it on every render cycle.

I'm new to React, so I'm not sure what is the "React way" to do it. I recently found a `useMemo()` hook, which seems to do what I need. Here's my *simplified* code:

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';

const GamesPage = () => {
    const [games, setGames] = useState([]);
    const [gameTitle, setGameTitle] = useState('');
    const gamesGrouped = useMemo(() => games.reduce(
        (games, game) => {
            // heavy computation
        },
        []
    ), [games]);

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={gameTitle}
                onChange={event => setGameTitle(event.target.value)}
            />
            <button onClick={() => setGames(
                [...games, {title: gameTitle}]
            )}>Add game</button>
            <ul>
                {gamesGrouped.map(game => (
                    <li key={game.title}>{game.title}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default GamesPage;
```

Am I doing it right? Is there some potential trap behind my idea, like not computing when needed or computing when not necessary? Or is there some more straightforward way, without using `useMemo()`?

Bonus question: how to achieve this goal in class components?

Comment: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback other options in detail. useMemo seems to be a good solution for heavy calculation performance.